# Completely turn off HTML intellisense in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to disable the intellisense when working in HTML?   The pop-up covers what I am typing which I find extremely annoying.

[image]

It's also completely useless because it on selecting it doubles up the name.  For example, if I'm applying the 'btn-primary' class to a button as I type 'btn-' and then select it from the list, it makes it 'btn-btn-primary'.

I just want to disable it.  I've gone into Options and turned off auto-complete under Intellisense and I've disabled the Intellicode extension.   Still shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to uncheck the "Auto list members" option under ASP.NET Web Forms to turn off the intellisense.

[image]

Comment: Next question: How the heck do you turn intellisense ON? (for Webforms)?  Some of use have to work on antiquated tech, and VS2022 abandoned intellisense!!!